# If statement comparing two string ee variables won't return false

Tags: conditionals, categories, segments

I have the following code in a template:

```
segment is: {segment_3} <br /> 
category is: {category_url_title}<br />
{if {segment_3} == {category_url_title}}
submenu goes here
{/if}
```

It gives the following output for categories that do not match the URL:

```
segment is: evaporated-apples
category is: frozen-apples 
submenu goes here
```

If I compare to a string literal, e.g., `{segment_3} == "bacon"`, the conditional returns false. Why does comparing two variables that contain different strings return true?

Comment: Try by using like {if "{segment_3}" == "{category_url_title}"} ###### {/if}

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it. Would you mind adding it as an answer so I can mark it? Bonus: do you know why it would resolve as true when I did it without quotes?

Comment: Yes sure, I posted my answer also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you were comparing 2 variables (string) without quotes so both variables will be considered as TRUE i.e `{if TRUE == TRUE} #### {/if}`. In the same way when you put a single variable tag in if condition like `{if variable_name} #### {/if} OR {if {variable_name}} #### {/if}`

Having the quotes (single or double), EE considers the variable/s tag value as single string value and get compared correctly like:

```
{if "{segment_3}" == "{category_url_title}"} ###### {/if}
```